# Может ли кодировка влиять на результат сравнения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Пишу игру "Города" на Python. Список городов лежит в файле .txt(с кодировкой windows-1251). Мне необходимо на моменте подбора города исключить следующий вариант ответа: 
Абаза(юзер) 
Абаза(комп). 
Делаю следующее условие(см. второе условие после "and" в цикле):

```
def bot_city_func(city):
answer = ""
with open(filename) as file:
    for city_b in file.readlines():
        if city_b in list_used_cities:
            continue

        elif city_b[0].lower() == city[-1].lower() \
                and city_b.lower() != city.lower():
            answer = city_b
            list_used_cities.append(city_b)
            break

    if answer == "":
        answer = "Ваш город не существует или введён на другом языке."
return answer
```

Но он всё равно пропускает город Абаза, и отвечает пользователю по сути тем же городом который он написал, **может дело в кодировке и поэтому Python считает что это разные слова?**

Вот код остальной программы:

```
userCity = ""
while userCity != 'q':
    print("Введите 'q' для завершения игры")
    userCity = input("Введите город\n")
    bot_city = bot_city_func(userCity)
    if len(bot_city) > 8:
        print(bot_city)
        quit()
    bot_city = bot_city.split()
    print(bot_city[0] + "\nВам на " + bot_city[0][-1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут две проблемы

1. Да, дело в кодировке (что легко провряется выводом прочитанного текста, `print (city_b)` вместо "Абакан" выведет "Àáàêàí" и т.д.) , поэтому при открытии файла кодировку нужно явно указать:

   `with open(filename, encoding="cp1251") as file:`
2. Последний символ в `city_b`  будет не последняя буква в названии города, а символ перевода строки `\n`, поэтому надо его отрезать:

   `for city_b in file.readlines():
       city_b = city_b[0:-1]`

Comment: Спасибо, на сохраню ваш ответ как заметку на будущее.

Comment: Ну, так символ перевода строки обрезать - не дело. А если там `\r\n`?. `city_b = city_b.strip()`